# Django sub template not appearing in outputted html

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm working with django 1.10 and python 3.6 in win 10.

In my main template (index.html) I have:

```
          <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h2 class="section-heading">We can help:</h2>
                    {% block 'body' %}
                    {% endblock %}

            </div>
```

need3.html template:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block 'body' %}
<p><big>Hello, ......
{% endblock %}
```

my code has:

```
def index(request):

    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'hero_phrase': 'Would you be interested in x?','body':'need3.html'})
```

However as you can see in the screenshot need3 template does not show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `index` function, you are rendering the `index.html` template.

So, if you want your `need3.html` template to show within your `index` template, you just need to [include](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include) it your main template:

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-6">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <h2 class="section-heading">We can help:</h2>
          {% include ´need3.html´ %}
</div>
```

The other way around would be to render the `need3.html` template inside your index function:

```
def index(request):

    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'need3.html', {'form': form, 'hero_phrase': 'Would you be interested in x?','body':'need3.html'})
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess is this

```
{% block 'body' %}
```

you don't need to make body string, just use it like this

```
{% block body %}
```

Comment: sorry, just tried that, but no change and no errors